# Microservices Data Access layer and Developer maintenance

Tags: microservices, soa

We want to add an UpdateDatetime column in a SQL database, when an entry is changed.

In Microservices Architecture, (a) would all 3 services which access the table, need to now include Updatedate in their API,  (b) Or would Microservices share a same DataAccess Layer?

If letter (a), is their any method to make development easier?

We are inquiring about developer maintenance associated with Microservices, since we may have 10 applications which interact with 1 table. If something is wrong in the table or column is added, we need to look/modify code through 10 app locations, as opposed to 1 location in Service Oriented Architecture.

[image]

Comment: If a single table is shared by 3 microservices, you aren't following microservices architecture. Each microservice owns its data, it's not shared. Your microservices layout is completely wrong, how come 3 different microservices have an order service?

Comment: well, we haven't built the system yet, I am a rookie programmer trying to learn, thank you, you might have answered my question, feel free to place in answer, I can accept send points  !

Comment: by the way, I grabbed the graph from youtube tutorial, 11:21 in this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EpyPFnjue38&t=682s

Comment: Not only is it one single order service in (a) but its also 3 databases. Something isn't adding up. I think I have a proper solution given the domain but (a) doesn't seem to be a viable solution at all.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a little off because the diagram in (a) actually doesn't make much sense but given the domain and what I understand. I think the proper solution is that you'll have the order service at the same level as your other microservices, customer management, warehouse management, and order fulfillment in this case. In total, that'll be four microservices.

When an order is created, it can propagate a message to a message bus where the other three services that are interested in servicing the order will get the event and update the order accordingly. If there are different steps to complete the order, you can also pipeline this with something like a queue where it moves from one topic to another where the respective service will update it accordingly.